# How to find LayoutParams of Android objects

Tags: android, layout

This is a ridiculously simple question. I am trying to find a list of LayoutParams for an ImageButton. Again the documentation at developer.android.com is driving my insane (it has to be the worst in the known universe).

Can someone please point me at the reference that will explain/list the layoutparams.

Comment: Have you ever read it? I dont know anyone who found it this difficult.

Comment: It takes a while to get use to @Neil once you realize what it means its simple

Comment: @Ajinkya, yes, spent hours looking through it, sometimes things are easy to find many times they are not. It is easy to find the stuff you already know :).

Comment: @Neil: Yes that's true.Even I am not that much familiar with android, I just started playing with it. I found it pretty easy even though I dont know anything about it.

Comment: There you go, you both say it is simple but neither of you told me where to look :(. It seems that I need to look for FrameLayout parameters not ImageButton parameters....the search continues.

Comment: Turns out if it is not there it is hard to find.... who would have guessed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "list of LayoutParams for an ImageButton".  An ImageButton is not a ViewGroup, so does not have LayoutParams associated with it.  The LayoutParams are for the *parent* of the view, to tell it how it should perform layout of the view.  So if you have your ImageButton *inside* of a LinearLayout, then the LayoutParams on it are LinearLayout.LayoutParams.

Put another way, there are an infinite number of possible LayoutParams for ImageButton, because you can make an infinite number of possible layout managers to put it in. :)

Comment: Yes, hackbod just realised that moments ago. I think I am attempting the impossible. I want to move my ImageButton around inside my framelayout and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html is not filling me with confidence.  I have done it with objects of my own design where I set the Region, maybe I need to investigate that some more.

Answer (score 1):

see, reference and let us know, what exactly you face issue in getting layout params, and to get layout params, use

view.getLayoutParams() method.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html